# Remoteness Measurements or Accessibility Models in Rural Areas in Africa

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, grids-graticules

I have a points shapefile (villages) that are located in remote areas in Africa. I need to give each village a measure of "remoteness." I dont just want to do a "as the crow flies" calculation from the village point to the nearest paved road. Can anyone give me specific instructions on how to do so? I'm using ArcGIS.

I know there are things like Grass R walk module and Naismith's Rule/Dijkstra's Shortest path Algorithm and using some combination of slope and topo rasters, but very specific instructions are much needed. I have a point shapefile with all the village points and a roads shapefile (but the villages are obviously very far away from the road network for the most part - at least the road network shapefile that is available to me)

Answer (score 1):

There is the Travel time to major cities: A global map of Accessibility dataset which you can down [here](http://forobs.jrc.ec.europa.eu/products/gam/).

This may not be exactly what you want as it is travel times to major populations but their [methodology](http://forobs.jrc.ec.europa.eu/products/gam/description.php) will help you create your own remoteness map.

Comment: I actually have been using Harvest Choices travel time to market centers, which seems to be similar. This methodology page you provided is useful, though definitely has many complicated facets to it.